# Magento 1.8.0.0 - Promotion > Catalog price rules does not work when condition is set

Tags: magento

I just installed a fresh Magento 1.8.0.0 with sample data.

Now I create a "Catalog price rule" with ALL websites and customer groups, and add a SKU condition, and give it 50% discount.

The price does not work.

If I remove the condition, the price works perfect.

I have checked with `$collection->count` and this gives me 1, so the collection of rules are found, but not applied.

I have

- pushed the "Apply rules" button several times.
- Removed /var/cache* and cleared the cache in magento administration
- Run reindex

But nothing works.

And as this is a totally fresh magento 1.8 no extensions are installed

[Edit]
Added some images to show how the rule looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWvNp.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug/feature in 1.8, Catalog Rules with conditions for attributes with Global scope do not work correcty. Took me days to figure it out.

This repository contains [an workaround](https://bitbucket.org/gferon/magento-1.8-catalogrule-fix/overview) (which I haven't tried) and some more detail on the issue.

Comment: Same here on 1.8 ... it sounds like big bug to me

Comment: And here is the [fix](https://bitbucket.org/gferon/magento-1.8-catalogrule-fix/overview) thats somehow fixes it

Answer (score 0):

If you're unfamiliar with bitbucket (as I was), here's the fix:

On line 95/96 of the file...

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php
```

Change this

```
$productValues  = isset($this->_entityAttributeValues[$object->getId()])
            ? $this->_entityAttributeValues[$object->getId()] : array();
```

to this

```
$productValues  = isset($this->_entityAttributeValues[$object->getId()])
            ? $this->_entityAttributeValues[$object->getId()] : array($defaultStoreId => $object->getData($this->getAttribute()));
```

Fixed my issue in v1.8.1.